# How to have Range be Nothing initially?

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: this works if I have it at the top of ThisWorkbook, but not if it's below another `Workbook_SheetChange` event

I am trying to make comments appear when I have a cell selected so I don't have to grab the mouse and hover over the cell.  I have multiple worksheets so this code is the workbook:

```
Public FRg As Range
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   'Update 20140909
    If Not FRg Is Nothing Then
        FRg.Comment.Visible = False
    End If
    If Not Target.Comment Is Nothing Then
        Target.Comment.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

I get an error at the first `if` saying `Object Required`

I think the FRg is basically to keep track of the last comment so I don't end up with comments STAYING ON after I navigate away from a cell, but maybe it needs to be something initially?

UPDATE:

I've changed the code slightly:

```
Public FRg As Range

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   'Update 20140909
    If Not FRg Is Nothing Then
        If Not FRg.Comment Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox "Hiding comment in cell w text: " & FRg.Value
            FRg.Comment.Visible = False
            Set FRg = Nothing
            'MsgBox "previous comment turned off"
        End If
    End If
    If Not Target.Comment Is Nothing Then
        Target.Comment.Visible = True
        Set FRg = Target
        Again = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me. `FRg` will be nothing as you have not assigned it to a range, or have you elsewhere?

Comment: I haven't assigned ```FRg``` to anything else, there is a Workbook_SheetChange sub above it in ThisWorkbook though

Comment: You can only have one type of change_event... you need to use an if-statement or switch to allow more than one.

Comment: Oh I see...  What is the sub then?  Seems like sheetChange is fundamentally a different event than sheetSelectionChange?

Comment: @Cyril - they're different events, change and selectionchange.

Comment: @SJR my bad, i thought i read that as Workbook_SheetChange in both the code and the top line of the post... sorry!

Comment: Does the code work if you just declare `Dim FRg As Range` inside the event code?

Comment: Aren't you assuming that `FRg` actually has a comment? What if `FRg.Comment` is actually `Nothing`?

Comment: Similar to SJR's comment about having FRg inside of the code, have you attempted to publicly declare FRg inside of a standard module, then reference in the Change_Event, e.g., `Module1.FRg`?

Comment: @BigBen - as `FRg` is never defined that line will never be executed?

Comment: @SJR I was assuming that `FRg` is `Set` somewhere but maybe that's not true, but the point is still valid, you need to test if it has a comment before attempting to set the visibility.

Comment: OP - what is the point of `FRg`? Where is it `Set`? If it's not used anywhere, then it should be ... deleted.

Comment: @BigBen - that was my first thought but OP says no. Which begs the question: what is the point?

Comment: So regarding ```FRg``` - when the selection goes from a cell with a comment to a new cell, I need the comment in the (now previously selected) cell to turn off.  Since the event only holds onto the cell I'm currently selecting (```Target```), I need some other variable (that's not set within the current instance of the change event, rather, the previous one), to keep track of which comment to turn off.  It is initially set to Nothing, I think.

Comment: No repro with your revised code.

Comment: @BigBen what do you mean by no repo?

Comment: No repro - unable to reproduce any error.

Comment: In order to propose a solution, please let us know if the variable `FRg` is used by the `Workbook_SheetChange` or any other procedure in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy should be to use `FRg` to track the last shown comment, and `Target` display a comment, if it exists.

Since you want this to be workbook wide,  you'll also need to handle a sheet change event too.

Something like this

```
Dim LastSh As Object
Dim FRg As Range

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Not (LastSh Is Sh) Then
        If Not FRg Is Nothing Then
            FRg.Comment.Visible = False
        End If
        If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
            ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = True
            Set LastSh = Sh
            Set FRg = ActiveCell
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not FRg Is Nothing Then
        FRg.Comment.Visible = False
    End If

    If Not Target.Comment Is Nothing Then
        Target.Comment.Visible = True
        Set FRg = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration:

```
Public FRg As Range
```

must always be at the top of the page, above all other subs in that sheet/book/module.

The remainder of the code can sit anywhere, but your declarations at the sheet/book/module level must come first. The reason you get the error is because when you put other code above the declaration, Excel ignores your erroneous declaration sitting between the subs and sets the undeclared variable "Frg" as a variant (which isn't an object) and is why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** The line `If Not FRg Is Nothing Then` generates the error: `Object Required`

Nevertheless, I could only reproduce error 424 when the `FRg` is defined as a `variant` instead of a range (see [Object required (Error 424)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-required-error-424))

[image]

When `FRg` is defined as a range the line `FRg.Comment.Visible = False` could generate an error 91 when the range does not have a comment.

**Objective**: To toggle the cells' comments visibility as the cells are selected\unselected.

**Solution:** This proposed solution is triggered by the workbook event: `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`. Bear in mind that the Target range used by this event could include several areas as well as several cells (another alternative is to apply the procedure only to the `ActiveCell`)

**Procedure:** This procedure performs the following steps:
1.  Hides the comments for the previously selected range (`rPrior`), regardless of the parent worksheet been active or not.
2.  Shows the comments, if any, of the cell in the selected range.
3.  Creates a static range with the cell with comments for each run in order to apply step 1 in the next run (see [Static statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement)).

Copy this procedurein the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Cells_Toggle_Comments(ByVal rTrg As Range)
Static rPrior As Range
Dim blShow As Boolean
Dim rTemp As Range, rArea As Range, rCll As Range

    Rem Hide comments from prior event
    blShow = False
    If Not (rPrior Is Nothing) Then
        Set rTemp = rPrior
        GoSub Rng_Comments_Toggle
        Set rTemp = Nothing
        Set rPrior = Nothing
    End If

    blShow = True
    Set rTemp = rTrg
    GoSub Rng_Comments_Toggle
    Set rTemp = Nothing

Exit Sub

Rng_Comments_Toggle:
    For Each rArea In rTemp.Areas
        For Each rCll In rArea.Cells
            With rCll
                If Not (.Comment Is Nothing) Then
                    .Comment.Visible = blShow
                    If blShow Then
                        If rPrior Is Nothing Then
                            Set rPrior = rCll
                        Else
                            Set rPrior = Union(rPrior, rCll)
    End If: End If: End If: End With: Next: Next
    Return

    End Sub
```

The Procedure should be called in this manner from the workbook event `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Cells_Toggle_Comments(Target)
    End Sub
```